# PDO Statement Taking 400x Longer Than MySQL CLI

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am running a PDO prepared statement to select from a table of around ~6k rows. This particular query ends up returning all of the rows due to the WHERE statement which has ~5k pIds. The table has an index on the pId column as well.

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE pId in (?, ? ,? ....)
```

This query takes 4.5 seconds to run in php and when run in the MySQL CLI it takes .01 seconds. The EXPLAIN statement for PHP and MySQL are the same, both are **NOT** using the index on pId. I think this is due to the fact that MySQL is aware that it is returning the entire table and does not need to use the index.

I know there's some overhead with prepared statements but I am running a very similar query (different table name) elsewhere and it's not taking close to as long (~.9 seconds). Any ideas?

PHP Version: 5.5

MySql Version: 5.6

Comment: Does the `pIds` used in `in` clause came from another query? If so, you can rewrite using `exists`

Comment: PDO has to establish connection in order to perform operations. Set pooling to true, and try executing this statement few times.

Comment: Is it faster with `EMULATE_PREPARES`?

Comment: Are you using prepared statements on the CLI?

Comment: I'm questioning what is included in the 4.5 seconds. Is that measured around just the `execute`. Does that include the time for the `bindValue` calls? The `prepare` call? Does that include the time for `bindResult` calls, and the time to fetch and process the rows? Is PDO using server side prepare, or emulated prepares on the client side? For comparison, what is the time when values are incorporated into the SQL text with no bindValue calls? Also, what's the execution time for the CLI when the query cache isn't involved `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM` ?

Comment: @bassxzero I am not, I wasn't aware I could use prepared statements on the CLI but also never even looked. I am aware that running the SQL command with the values already in the "where" statement will be faster but again 400 times fast seems crazy. Also I'm running an identical query just on a different table and it takes a quarter of the time in PHP.

Comment: @shreddish ~6k ids being prepared is a non-trivial task and I would bet that's why your query is so slow. However, you won't know for sure until you test it. Right now it feels like you're comparing apples to oranges. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: @spencer7593 I'll try and get some more granular PDO profiling. Right now I'm calling a wrapper function so all my PDO statements are getting grouped together. As for emulate prepare that is set to false.

Comment: @bassxzero that makes sense that preparing that statement would have some overhead, but why wouldn't I see that overhead on an identical prepared query just different table?

Comment: @shreddish It's again probably an apples to oranges problem. Do both tables have a similar number of rows, are you querying both tables on an index, are both tables partitioned the same, etc. ?

Comment: @bassxzero yes the other table is indexed on pId and has around ~5.5k rows and partitioned the same

Comment: There might be something that you're missing. You'll never know until you test it mate. I would try the same prepared query on the CLI and see if the time changes.

Comment: @spencer7593 you were on to something, I may be conflating that 4.5 seconds with the query execution time. It seems that the PDO fetchAll is taking up ~90% of the time for this query and actually the rest of my queries as well. Why would fetchAll be much longer on this query when compared to the "identical" query and with very similar result length?

Comment: @bassxzero well looks like you were onto something as well haha, my approach to creating these prepared statements was flawed in the efficiency department. Instead of creating ~6k values in the "where" statement I changed it to a single value and imploded my pIds array to be prepared. This reduced the time SIGNIFICANTLY, thank you!

Comment: @shreddish "imploded my pIds array" - This would result in something like `WHERE pid IN ('3,6,8,...')` which is then casted to INT as `3`. Of course it would run faster. But do you also get the same result? :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel haha was just about to correct myself on this got a little too excited with the result and didn't bother to actually check the output... I am not getting the same result. Is there a way I can do something similar to this to avoid preparing ~6k values?

Comment: There is an issue with PDO. Here is a related unsolved question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350718/why-are-certain-types-of-prepared-queries-using-pdo-in-php-with-mysql-slow .. I see - you already found that.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Ugh completely forgot about that... This has been an on going optimization process that has been put on the back burner for months now and diving back into I clearly forgot about my previous research. Should I mark as duplicate or remove this?

Comment: Don't delete it. Duplicate is fine, if you think it's the same problem. The other question describes the problem pretty well. Also consider to post a bug report.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel you were pretty active on that other question. Do you have any recommendations for a work around on this?  I tried removing the IN clause and used 'WHERE pId = ? OR pId = ?...' but did not improve the time. It seems the only other options, if I want to keep prepared statements, are switch to mysqli or breakup my queries.

Comment: @shreddish Here is a related bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53458

Comment: @shreddish Workaround: If the ids come from the DB - use a JOIN or `IN (<subquery>)`. If they don't - store them into a temporary table first.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the slowness is in fetching the rows, the number of rows being returned, rather than the 5000+ bind placeholders in the statement. `pId IN ( ? , ? , ... , ? )`

My suggestion would be to test returning only a single row, supply one value that is known to exist/return a row, and then 4999+ values that are known not to exist/not to return a row.

For example, if we know the highest pId value in the table, use values higher than that, supply bind values for a statement like this

```
 ... pId IN ( ? , ? , ? , ... , ? )
```

so the result would be equivalent to running

```
 ... pId IN ( 99999999 , 99999998 , 99999997 , ... , 42 )
```

which would be the same result we would get running

```
 ... pId IN ( 42 )
```

Our expectation would be to return just one row ( pId = 42 ).

Then compare the timing of that ( 5000+ bind values returning 1 row ) to two bind values returning a single row

```
 ... pId IN ( 99999999 , 42 )
```

And see if there is a significant difference in performance.

(There's more work to do with 5000+ bind values, but I wouldn't expect a *huge* difference, but it should be tested.

---

Thinking on it a bit, it might be easier to setup a test using all the existing bind values, and just adding `LIMIT 2` to the end of the query. (I'm not sure if MySQL has some performance enhancements for `LIMIT 2`.

It maybe better to add a condition like `AND pId * 10 = 420`

The goal is to supply a whole slew of bind values but only return one or two rows.

---

Another test would be to return a whole slew of rows, but using only a couple of bind values.  Maybe a range condition that returns 5000+ rows.

The query could be:

```
 ... pId >= ? AND pId <= ?
```

with a large enough range between the provided values that we get in the neighborhood of 5000 rows.

And compare performance.

My prediction (guess?) is that performance will be correlated more with the number of rows returned, rather than the number of bind values.

---

I'm not sure if this is an answer to your question, but it's the approach I would take to answer the question ... "what is causing this to be slow, the number of bind values, or the number of rows returned?"

Comment: "what is causing this to be slow, the number of bind values, or the number of rows returned?" - It's both - thus *O(n²)*

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: to be confirmed with some testing... my suspicion is that that the number of bind values doesn't contribute that much to the total elapsed time. The tests I recommend in this answer should give an indication which factor (number of bind values, or number or rows returned) is actually contributing to the elapsed time. (I'm assuming that the bind values are being provided with `bindValue`, and not `bindParam`, or maybe that doesn't make a difference.)

Comment: My comment is based on tests. Execute a stupid test query like `select * from t where id in (?, .. , ?) or 1=1 limit $numRows`. Start with 1000 parameters and limit 1000. Then increase the number of parameters. You will see increasing fetch time with the same result set.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: and the tests are performed using `bindValue` and not `bindParam`, correct?

Comment: They are performed using `exec($params)`. But why do you think it would matter? Most time is spent with `fetch()` or `fetchAll()`.