# Why is mysql only creating temp tables when used with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo, command-line-interface

I have a query with three joins, which returns a few hundred rows. When I run it from the command line, it consistently takes between 8 and 9 seconds to complete. However, when I run it via PDO, it usually takes around 2 minutes 40 seconds to complete. When I run "show processlist" while it is running, I see that most of the time is spent in state "Copying to tmp table", which only seems to happen when I run it through PDO.

To summarize:

```
<? $pdo->prepare($query)->execute(); ?> => takes 2 minutes 40
$ echo $query | mysql; => takes 8 seconds
```

Why is this? It's exactly the same query; I'm literally copying and pasting it between php and the command line. So, why is it taking so much longer when pdo does it? And more importantly, how can I make the execution faster without changing the query?

Comment: could you show the query?

Comment: We need the query, have you tried an explain on both the queries ran by PDO and the one in console?

Comment: Do the EXPLAIN of the query and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

In general running queries through PDO will be slower than running them natively. This is because you have, as far as I know, three layers you're going through by using PDO (under PDO you got the ODBC). So having a slower PDO as compared to native is normal.

Since you're comparing times on identical query I think that you have a lot of rows. I would asume that PDO has trouble to consume a lot of rows at the same speed as your native can deliver them so that slows down the process.

If by any chance you combine this with not using an index for whatever reason than the time diference is even greater. In this regard you could check if the character set of the two connections is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Specify exact argument types (integer,string) using [bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) method. Otherwise Mysql may not use index.

Looks similar to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350718/why-are-certain-types-of-prepared-queries-using-pdo-in-php-with-mysql-slow)