# PDO Bindings have significant performance impacts

Tags: php, sql, performance, pdo, sql-server-2012

I have a particular query that, for some reason, seems to have terrible performance when using PDO bindings (via `$statement->execute($bindings)`). I don't seem to have this problem with other queries, so I'm not certain if it's *this* query in general, or if there's a larger underlying problem with PDO bindings.

Essentially, when I run the statement without bindings (by manually injecting the raw bindings into the query string myself [Which I understand is unsafe and may cause exposure to SQL injection]), the statement runs in about 100ms to 200ms, which is reasonable for our application. Most queries typically have this speed *with* bindings, but for whatever reason, this one doesn't.

When I run the statement naturally through our framework, the bindings are passed to the PDO instance. Running the query this way causes it to take 40,000ms (40s), which is *way* higher than what is to be expected.

I've tried every combination I can think of to find to root cause of the problem, and I'm certain that it's the PDO bindings. I even tried the same query without PDO, and I don't have the same issues. Running the raw query in the RDS takes only 80ms (which is faster due to less overhead).

We've also updated PHP, Apache, and our MSSQL/ODBC drivers to their latest versions, which didn't change the performance.

I have no idea why the PDO bindings are this slow, and I don't know what our exposure is to this apparent slowness (as other queries may be slow in our application due to this issue). I know that this query is our only known instance of the problem right now.

The query itself:

```
SELECT 
    top 10 [cars].[id], 
    [cars].[sponsor_id] 
FROM [cars] 
    INNER JOIN [drivers_cars]
        ON [cars].[id] = [drivers_cars].[car_id] 
            AND [drivers_cars].[driver_type_id] = ? -- 1
    INNER JOIN [drivers]
        ON [drivers_cars].[driver_id] = [drivers].[id] 
            AND [drivers].[deleted_at] IS NULL 
WHERE [cars].[deleted_at] IS NULL 
    AND (
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM [drivers] 
                INNER JOIN [drivers_cars]
                    ON [drivers].[id] = [drivers_cars].[driver_id] 
            WHERE [drivers_cars].[car_id] = [cars].[id] 
            AND (
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM [drivers_sponsors] 
                    WHERE [drivers_sponsors].[driver_id] = [drivers].[id] 
                        AND [drivers_sponsors].[driver_client_id] LIKE '469%'
                ) >= ? -- 1
                OR [drivers].[student_id] LIKE ? -- '469%'
                OR (
                    SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM [drivers_contacts] 
                    WHERE [drivers_contacts].[driver_id] = [drivers].[id] 
                        AND [contact_type] IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) -- (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
                        AND [phone_number] LIKE ? -- '469%'
                        AND [drivers_contacts].[deleted_at] IS NULL
                ) >= 1
            ) 
            AND [drivers].[deleted_at] IS NULL 
            AND [drivers_cars].[deleted_at] IS NULL
        ) >= 1 
        OR [cars].[sponsor_car_id] LIKE ? -- '469%'
    ) 
ORDER BY [drivers].[last_name] ASC
```

The bindings (which replaces the ?s in the query):

```
"bindings" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => "469%",
    3 => 1,
    4 => 2,
    5 => 3,
    6 => 4,
    7 => 5,
    8 => 6,
    9 => "469%",
    10 => "469%",
]
```

The PDO instance:

```
"pdo" => PDO {#131
    inTransaction: false
    attributes: array:11 [
        "CASE" => NATURAL
        "ERRMODE" => EXCEPTION
        "PERSISTENT" => false
        "DRIVER_NAME" => "sqlsrv"
        "SERVER_INFO" => array:3 [
            "CurrentDatabase" => "{{ DATABASE NAME }}"
            "SQLServerVersion" => "12.00.5207"
            "SQLServerName" => "{{ SERVER NAME }}"
        ]
        "ORACLE_NULLS" => NATURAL
        "CLIENT_VERSION" => array:4 [
            "DriverDllName" => "msodbcsql13.dll"
            "DriverODBCVer" => "03.80"
            "DriverVer" => "13.00.0811"
            "ExtensionVer" => "4.1.7-preview+9506"
        ]
        "SERVER_VERSION" => "12.00.5207"
        "STATEMENT_CLASS" => array:1 [
            0 => "PDOStatement"
        ]
        "STRINGIFY_FETCHES" => false
        "DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE" => BOTH
    ]
}
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350718/why-are-certain-types-of-prepared-queries-using-pdo-in-php-with-mysql-slow][1]

Comment: First recommendation would be to run a profiler like [xhprof](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xhprof.php) to identify exactly where the time is being spent.

Comment: Looks like xhprof is abandonded. [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) is another option.